# How to escape Multi Line string

Tags: c#, string, paypal-sandbox

I have the code

```
var body = @"{
                  ""sender_batch_header"": {
                    ""email_subject"": ""You have a payment"",
                    ""sender_batch_id"": ""batch-1564759643870""
                  },
                  ""items"": [
                    {
                      ""recipient_type"": ""PHONE"",
                      ""amount"": {
                        ""value"": ""1.00"",
                        ""currency"": ""USD""
                      },
                      ""receiver"": ""4087811638"",
                      ""note"": ""Payouts sample transaction"",
                      ""sender_item_id"": ""item-1-1564759643870""
                    },
                    {
                      ""recipient_type"": ""EMAIL"",
                      ""amount"": {
                        ""value"": ""1.00"",
                        ""currency"": ""USD""
                      },
                      ""receiver"": ""ps-rec@paypal.com"",
                      ""note"": ""Payouts sample transaction"",
                      ""sender_item_id"": ""item-2-1564759643870""
                    },
                    {
                      ""recipient_type"": ""PAYPAL_ID"",
                      ""amount"": {
                        ""value"": ""1.00"",
                        ""currency"": ""USD""
                      },
                      ""receiver"": ""FSMRBANCV8PSG"",
                      ""note"": ""Payouts sample transaction"",
                      ""sender_item_id"": ""item-3-1564759643871""
                    }
                  ]
                }";
```

I want the recipiant's email to be a string/ variable, and so I need to escape the double quote, however nothing Ive tried online works. Is this possible?
this code is taken from https://www.paypal.com/apex/product-profile/payouts/createPayouts

I cant use \ to escape it, because I have the modifier @, and its in double quotes, so I cant escape it with more quotes.

I want to make EMAIL a variable that can be changed, not a part of the string's text.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific in what you want to do and what's not working?

Comment: @LukedukeAnimations check my answer and mark if helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just break the `@string` on the part you need to create a variable. Then after adding the variable, start the string again with `@string`

```
var emailVar = ""; //email input

var body = @"{
              ""sender_batch_header"": {
                ""email_subject"": ""You have a payment"",
                ""sender_batch_id"": ""batch-1564759643870""
              },
              ""items"": [
                {
                  ""recipient_type"": ""PHONE"",
                  ""amount"": {
                    ""value"": ""1.00"",
                    ""currency"": ""USD""
                  },
                  ""receiver"": ""4087811638"",
                  ""note"": ""Payouts sample transaction"",
                  ""sender_item_id"": ""item-1-1564759643870""
                },
                {
                  ""recipient_type"": " + "\"" + emailVar + "\"" + @",
                  ""amount"": {
                    ""value"": ""1.00"",
                    ""currency"": ""USD""
                  },
                  ""receiver"": ""ps-rec@paypal.com"",
                  ""note"": ""Payouts sample transaction"",
                  ""sender_item_id"": ""item-2-1564759643870""
                },
                {
                  ""recipient_type"": ""PAYPAL_ID"",
                  ""amount"": {
                    ""value"": ""1.00"",
                    ""currency"": ""USD""
                  },
                  ""receiver"": ""FSMRBANCV8PSG"",
                  ""note"": ""Payouts sample transaction"",
                  ""sender_item_id"": ""item-3-1564759643871""
                }
              ]
            }";
```

Comment: If `emailVar` comes from an untrusted source, including it into the string like this can be used for a code injection attack. So, use an escaping function like `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` on the string before using it to build JSon manually.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building the json string directly, use [C# object literal notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) to first create the data structure as a .net object and then let .net do the encoding for you.

```
string eMailAddress = "someone@somewhere.net";

// Create the data using object literal notation in C#
var data = new
{
    sender_batch_header = new
    {
        email_subject = "You have a payment",
        sender_batch_id = "batch-1564759643870"
    },
    items = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            recipient_type = "PHONE",
            amount = new
            {
                value = 1,
                currency = "USD"
            },
            receiver = "4087811638",
            note = "Payouts sample transaction",
            sender_item_id = "item-1-1564759643870"
        },
        new
        {
            recipient_type = "EMAIL",
            amount = new
            {
                value = 1,
                currency = "USD"
            },
            receiver = eMailAddress,
            note = "Payouts sample transaction",
            sender_item_id = "item-2-1564759643870"
        }
    }
};

// Let .net translate it to json either using JavaScriptSerializer (You have to reference system.web.extensions)
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);

// or you could use JSON.net from NewtonSoft
// string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);

MessageBox.Show(json);
```

See also

- [How do I turn a C# object into a JSON string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net)
- [Issues creating object literal using anonymous types in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795296/issues-creating-object-literal-using-anonymous-types-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This is a really clean approach. In my case, I needed an array, which is supported as well: `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            new[] {
                new {
                    op = "replace",
                    path = "/title",
                    value = newTitle
                }
            }  `